# Bind navigation property from many-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing referral user logic and my current working implementation is

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UserReferral? ReferringUser { get; set; }
    public List<UserReferral> ReferredUsers { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class UserReferral
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ReferringUserId { get; set; }
    public int ReferredUserId { get; set; }

    public User ReferringUser { get; set; } = null!;
    public User ReferredUser { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

As one can see on the User entity I have navigation properties to have direct access to reffering/referred users. My model configuration is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOne(u => u.ReferringUser)
    .WithOne(u => u.ReferredUser);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ReferredUsers)
    .WithOne(u => u.ReferringUser)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.ReferringUserId);
```

**Question**:
Is it possible to configure mapping to have referring and referred users on the User directly being able to include them skipping including the UserReferral like this?

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User? ReferringUser { get; set; }
    public List<User> ReferredUsers { get; set; } = null!;
}

_dbContext.Users
.Include(u => u.ReferringUser )
.Include(u => u.ReferredUsers )
```

I'm on the latest .NET 8 / EF-Core 8, NpgSql 8

Comment: ReferringUser and ReferredUser are the same. Why not use one class with a boolean or a reference to a status table to determine the user's state?

Comment: User, ReferringUser and ReferralUser are all of same type User. I have to know who referred who so I need both UserIds in the same UserReferral row

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though User table will need to have a null-able FK to it's Referring User. This can be exposed in the entity or a shadow property. In your case the mapping you had for the joining table would work with a declared ReferringUserId in the User entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ReferredUsers)
    .WithOne(u => u.ReferringUser)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.ReferringUserId);

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ReferringUserId { get; set; }
    public User? ReferringUser { get; set; }
    public List<User> ReferredUsers { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

A joining table is not needed in this case. Joining tables like UserReferral are for many-to-many relationships, which this isn't really that type of relationship, instead you are just wanting a self-referencing many-to-one.

The typical problem with self-referencing relationships is that the FK relationships typically need to be explicitly configured as when these are setup you might declare a ReferringUserId property and expect it to automatically be linked to the ReferringUser navigation property, but EF would instead try and locate a UserId1 column based on the type. With the explicit mapping you have linking the FK, it should just work with an optional ReferringUserId on the User table.

Comment: well, I've tried to avoid adding additional property on User which will be null in most cases so went many-to-many model. Is it not possible with additional UserReferral table?

Comment: I can't say it's "impossible", but a null-able self-referencing FK isn't anything to necessarily be problematic or wasteful. It's less potentially confusing IMHO than a joining table which could see a given user ID on either side of a relationship.

Comment: I'm familiar with your approach. My product is growing and I don't feel comfortable adding new columns which will be null in >90% of cases but it's matter of preference. I prefer adding new table instead. Thanks anyway.